# Excel - allocate weight based on text

Tags: excel

I have an risk control assessment where some controls are key and hold greater weight than non key controls.

```
Key   vaule (1-4)
Y       4
Y       3
N       2
N       2
```

I want the keys with a "Y" to be summed at a weight of 70% and the non-keys with an "N" to be summed at a weight of 30%.

If we add the column we get 11. However, I want the 7 (4+3) to be multiplied by 70% and the 4 (2+2) be multiplied by 30%.

There may be 4 rows or 40. There generally are only 1 or 2 key controls ("Y"), but, if there are 40 rows or controls, there may be up to 5 "Y"s.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When the "Y" items take 70% of the total, what does that look like?  How do you want it represented?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do what I think you want would be to create a third column that had formulas like this one:  =IF(A1="Y",B1*0.7,B1*0.3). Then, you could use the SUM function to add up all of the results. See the cells with formulas below.

```
Key  Value  Weighted Value
Y    1      =IF(A2="Y",B2*0.7,B2*0.3)
N    2      =IF(A3="Y",B3*0.7,B3*0.3)
N    3      =IF(A4="Y",B4*0.7,B4*0.3) 
Y    4      =IF(A5="Y",B5*0.7,B5*0.3)
            =SUM(C2:C5)
```

Here would be the result...

```
Key  Value  Weighted Value
Y    1      0.7
N    2      0.6
N    3      0.9
Y    4      2.8
            5
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can seen from @TimWilliams' comment, there is some uncertainty about your requirement but if it is weighting factors then the following formula might suit:

```
=IF(A2="Y",C$1*SUM(B:B)*B2/SUMIF(A:A,"=Y",B:B)/SUM(B:B),(1-C$1)*SUM(B:B)*B2/SUMIF(A:A,"=n",B:B)/SUM(B:B))
```

copied down to suit and assuming a layout as shown:

[image: SO18368762 example]